# Find the cartesian equation of: $r=2\cos\left(\frac {3\theta}{2}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I've managed to use identities to simplify it down to:
$$r = 2\left(\cos^3\left({\theta\over2}\right)-3\sin\left({\theta\over2}\right)\cos\left({\theta\over2}\right)\right)$$
using trig identities, but I am stuck now. Does this have a Cartesian equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**.  The difficulty is the half angle.  So:
$$\eqalign{r^2
  &=4\cos^2\Bigl(\frac{3\theta}{2}\Bigr)\cr
  &=2\bigl(1+\cos(3\theta)\bigr)\ .\cr}$$
Now you should be able to write in various ways $\cos(3\theta)$ in terms of $\cos\theta$ or $\sin\theta$ or both, and the rest should not be too difficult.  Good luck!

Comment: Of course! Why didn't I think of squaring the regular half angle identity. Thank you! I'll return when I've finished or run into another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I want to elaborate on David's answer but please give him the credit...

From David's result
$$
r^2 = 2 ( 4 \cos^3(\theta)- 3 \cos(\theta)+1)$$
Now $\cos(\theta) = x/r$ and hence
$$
r^2 =  {{8\,x^3}\over{r^3}}-{{6\,x}\over{r}}+2$$
cross multiplying we get
$$-8\,x^3+6\,r^2\,x+r^5-2\,r^3=0$$
Now substitute $r =\sqrt{y^2+x^2}$ to get
$$y^4\,\sqrt{y^2+x^2}+2\,x^2\,y^2\,\sqrt{y^2+x^2}-2\,y^2\,\sqrt{y^2+x
 ^2}+x^4\,\sqrt{y^2+x^2}-2\,x^2\,\sqrt{y^2+x^2}+6\,x\,y^2-2\,x^3=0$$

Here is the plot (remember to use $\theta = 0 \cdots 4 \pi$)

[image: Plot]

The above graph was produced using Octave (a free software similar to Matlab)
Here are the commands:

```
theta=0:0.001:4*pi;
r=2*cos(3*theta/2);
plot(r.*cos(theta), r.*sin(theta))
print -djpeg keanu.jpg
```

Added more info in response to OP's question:

You can isolate $\sqrt{y^2+x^2}$, square it to get

$$-y^{10}-5\,x^2\,y^8+4\,y^8-10\,x^4\,y^6+16\,x^2\,y^6-4\,y^6-10\,x^6
 \,y^4\\+24\,x^4\,y^4+24\,x^2\,y^4-5\,x^8\,y^2+16\,x^6\,y^2-36\,x^4\,y^
 2-x^{10}+4\,x^8=0$$
[I used maxima to do the work for me!]

You can sweep $x$ from $-2$ to $2$ and solve for $y$ using "roots" command and plot the result to get the pattern that you see.

This method is not very efficient but can be used for quick checks:
Here is octave script to check the plot. It has some extraneous solutions that have to be pruned (complex roots) but that is a lot more work!

```
h=@(x)sqrt(roots([-1,4-5*x^2,-10*x^4+16*x^2-4,...
 -10*x^6+24*x^4+24*x^2,...
 -5*x^8+16*x^6-36*x^4,4*x^8-x^10]));
hold on;
for x=-2:0.005:2 plot(x*ones(5,1), h(x), '.'); end
for x=-2:0.005:2 plot(x*ones(5,1), -h(x), '.'); end
hold off
```

Comment: Thank you for going through and solving this out. I came to the same result.

Comment: When I graph this relation, should it resemble the original polar equation?

Comment: yes, except you have an implicit function to graph.

Comment: When I graphed it using CountourPlot[] in Mathematica, it only appeared as one half of the original graph. However, replacing all the x's with (-x)'s reflected it across the y axis, therefore completing it. Is this just an issue with the square roots present?

Comment: Perhaps, you went for $\theta=0 \cdot \cdot 2 \pi$. You need to go to $4 \pi$ since you have half angles. See my output

Comment: Would you mind sending me your input for that graph?

Comment: Ah, that was a graph of the original $r = 2\cos\left(\frac {3\theta} {2} \right)$. I was referring to the graph of the new Cartesian relation that you concluded with.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Are the extraneous solutions found between about $y = -0.1$ and $y = 0.1$, as in this graph? http://i.imgur.com/87Iicn4.png